# Find how many days from begining of the month to current day (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How do I determine how many days in a month, from the first to the current day (could be anywhere into the month). So if I have a field that gives 6/01/12 5:32:13 PM and 6/07/12 5:33:04 PM how do I get the difference?

Comment: What version of oracle are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should do it:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MONTH') + 1 FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM sysdate) FROM dual;
```